# SUMIFS with criterion not in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I want to calculate sum by multiple criterias for the table:

```
    A      B      C    D
1  crit1 crit2 code   amount
2   a      b    code1  10
3   a      b    code3  20
4   a      b    code2  100
5   a      b    code1  80
6   a      b    code4  30
```

Also I have range of codes to exclude:

```
      A         B    C    D
     ...........
10  exclude rows
11  code1
12  code8
```

My formula for the marked result cell looks like this: `SUMIFS(D2:D6,A2:A6,"a",B2:B6,"b")`.
How can I change my `SUMIFS` formula to filter by codes that are not in *exclude codes* range (`A11:A12`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
            (A2:A6="a")  * (B2:B6="b") * ISNA(MATCH(C2:C6,A11:A12,0)),
            D2:D6)
```

`MATCH` returns an `#N/A!` error when it can't find the lookup value (code) in the lookup array (list excluded rows). `ISNA()` converts matches to `FALSE` and non-matches (`#N/A!`) to `TRUE`. These are then "and'ed" with your other criteria using the mathematical operator `*`; `TRUE` becomes 1 and `FALSE` becomes 0 in the process. `SUMPRODUCT` finally sums up the amounts that line up with 1's (and not those with 0's).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Jean-François Corbett's answer is by far the most appropriate and comprehensible here.

However, just to show that it can be still be achieved using `SUMIFS` (although at the cost of some convolutedness!):

`=SUM(MMULT(MMULT({1,1},SUMIFS(D2:D6,A2:A6,"a",B2:B6,"b",C2:C6,{"=","<>"}&A11:A12)),{-1;1}))/2`

Comment: Yes - not one which will make the textbooks!